# LC differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I want to solve the differential equation for the charge of an LC circuit:
$$d^{2} Q / d t^{2}+(1 / L C) Q=0$$

I create the characteristic equation:

$$\mu^{2}+\frac{1}{\mathrm{LC}}=0 \Rightarrow \mu^{2}=-\frac{1}{\mathrm{LC}} \Rightarrow \mu = \pm i \sqrt{\frac{1}{\mathrm{LC}}}= \pm i w_0\\$$
As a result, $$ q(t)=c_{1} e^{i\sqrt{\frac{1}{LC}}t}+c_2 e^{-i\sqrt{\frac{1}{LC}}t} \\
\Rightarrow q(t)=\left(c_{1}+c_{2}\right) \cos \left(w_{0} t\right)+i \cdot\left(c_{1}-c_{2}\right) \sin \left(w_{0} t\right)\\$$
But the charge is a real quantity, so: $$ q(t) \in R \Rightarrow c_{1}=c_{2} $$ Finally: $$ q(t)=2 c_{1} \cos \left(w_{0} t\right) \Rightarrow q(t)=C \cos \left(w_{0} t\right)
$$

My question is, how does the phase $\varphi$ occur in the equation?$$Q(t)=Q_{m} \cos \left(\omega_{0} t+\varphi\right)$$

Comment: $Q_m, \varphi$ are the two unknowns that can be determined once initial conditions are prescribed.

Comment: Based on the characteristic equation your solution should be of the form $$q(t)=A\cos (\omega_0 t)+B\sin (\omega_0 t), \qquad A,B \in \Bbb{R}.$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fact that $q(t)$ is real does not imply that $c_1=c_2$. $c_1$ and $c_2$ are complex numbers such that $C_1=c_1+c_2$ and $C_2=i(c_1-c_2)$ are real numbers and
$$q(t)=C_1\cos \left(w_{0} t\right)+C_2 \sin \left(w_{0} t\right).$$
Note that
$$q(t)=Q_{m} \cos \left(\omega_{0} t+\varphi\right)=(Q_m\cos(\phi))\cos(\omega_{0} t)+(-Q_m\sin(\phi))\sin(\omega_{0} t)$$
and therefore
$$\begin{cases}
C_1=Q_m\cos(\phi)\\
C_2=-Q_m\sin(\phi)
\end{cases}$$

Answer (score 1):

If you calculate the solution via complex solutions of the characteristic polynomial you can take complex constants as well. In order to end up with something real you have:
$$
c_1=a+ib\\
c_2=a-ib
$$
That yields the sine function as a solution as well as the cosine function.